# Rails 3.1.3: Why is this nested resource link_to deleting my user and not my post?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

New to rails and making a simple blog in rails 3.1.3 where a User has_many Posts and a Post belongs_to a User.  Whenever I try to delete a specific blog post for a specific user, I end up destroying the user but not the post...

1)  what am I doing wrong?
2)  For more experienced programmers, how did you learn what "object" arguments to pass and path syntax to use (e.g., edit_user_post_path(@user,post) ) when learning Rails routing?  Was it just a matter of trial and error and reading the API? (which is what I'm doing now).

**Code snippet from view index.html.erb where I am trying to destroy the post of a specific user**

```
#Navigate to http://localhost:3000/users/7/posts which brings up index.html.erb view:
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= post.content %></td>
   <td><%= post.title %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', ([@user, post] ) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_post_path(@user,post) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [@user, post], confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
```

The nested resource setup is as follows:

**Routes from routes.rb**

```
Simpleblog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end

  resources :posts
:
```

**Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :dependent=>:destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

**Post Controller code snippet**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :get_user
 :
 def index
    @posts = @user.posts
 :
 def show
     @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
  :
 def destroy
   @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to user_posts_url }
     format.json { head :ok }
   end
 end

 private
 def get_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one problem is that you have `belongs_to :user, :dependent=>:destroy` in your post which will delete the user when you delete the post. so i think this must go to the user-side, so when you delete the user you also delete the posts.

learning the routes is not an easy one, but you get used to it. a good point to start is by writing tests for them. this way you get a better understanding of how and where to put the objects/ids/parameters. in the end it's the same as it's defined in your routes.

Comment: Thank you, I was a little bleary-eyed last night trying to figure this out.